# BQ77915 - Is 3.0 V undervoltage good for Lithium batteries?

Tags: batteries, integrated-circuit, lithium-ion, bms

I'm considering to use BQ77915 in my design, but I've came across the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq77915.pdf?ts=1670571655231&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ77915) saying that the maximum undervoltage for cell is 3.0 V. As what I thought, the voltage on Lithium batteries (Li-Ion, Li-Po) shouldn't go below 3.7 V to not to get damaged. I'm not sure if this is safe for the batteries and if it won't damage them. Is it okay, or should I use another IC?

Comment: What does the datasheet for your cells say? 3.0 V is a common UVLO value.

Comment: This design is meant to be for general 18650 cells. If it's a common value, then it should be alright.

Comment: 3.7 or 3.8V is the average voltage across the range. 3.0 minimum is OK. 3.1V is better for the battery and helps cycle life.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Low=3.0 typ., Max = 4.2 typ. during CC charge and typ 3.7~3.8 when CV charge is cutoff after current drops below 10 to 5% and slightly discharge or long settling time.  If it fails to decline then a time duration indicates a faulty battery from leakage.

There is also an effective series resistance or ESR which rises sharply towards and below 3V then reduces when re-charged. Outside this range chemical degradation occurs.

Experience and Battery university website have tested to show if you use only 50% of the capacity each time you can get 10x to 100x more lifetime Ah capacity in charge cycles by reducing 4.2 to 4.0 and raised the minimum voltage to 40% SoC and variations similar to this. Also, the chemistry used in car batteries has far greater reliability and Mitsubishi guarantees only 10% loss after 10 years of daily use to 50% of total charge. I have one such ex-co-worker who got the 1st such car in Canada and his car is more than 10yrs old.  Also said it was the best winter car in Winnipeg. Instant heat. Instant start and extremely cheap electricity bill.

Comment: This is incorrect " ... typ 3.7~3.8 when CV charge is cutoff after current drops below 10 to 5% ..." --> I suspect you meant to write something different